# Unable to fill div with video in React js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

### **The goal**

The goal is to reproduce [this](https://www.meetup.com/pt-BR/) home page from meet up, where the video is placed bellow the navbar.

### **The issue**

Different from images, videos are difficult to tame inside the div element. The aspect ratio is kept, but  the video leaves white spaces in the div. As far as i know, `object-fit` is only supported by 'traditional' html. The attempts to make it work in React js `object-fit` failed. How to fully fill a div with a `video` tag in React js?

Link to code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-video-sandbox-forked-drm8o?file=/src/index.js

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your goal correctly, then this might be what you want:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-video-sandbox-forked-8lkmj?file=/src/index.js

I basically just tried to copy what meetup does.
To do this we don't need to use `object-fit`.
We can just write some regular CSS styling to achieve this.

To remove the white spaces you had, I just let the video wrapper element be 100% of the parent size (width & height), and then centered the video with flex-box.

I tried to add some descriptive comments to my fork of your codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you very much!